# Inner Join with conditions in R

Tags: r, merge, inner-join, dplyr

I want to do inner  join with the condition that it should give me subtraction of 2 columns.

```
df1 = data.frame(Term = c("T1","T2","T3"), Sec = c("s1","s2","s3"), Value =c(10,30,30))

df2 = data.frame(Term = c("T1","T2","T3"), Sec = c("s1","s3","s2"), Value =c(40,20,10)

 df1
 Term Sec Value
  T1  s1    10
  T2  s2    30
  T3  s3    30

  df2
  Term  Sec Value
  T1  s1    40
  T2  s3    20
  T3  s2    10
```

The result I want is

```
  Term  Sec Value
   T1   s1   30
   T2   s2   20
   T3   s3   10
```

Basically I am joining two tables and for the column value I am taking

```
Value=  abs(df1$Value - df2$Value)
```

I have struggled but could not found any way to do this conditional merge in base R. Probably if it is not possible with base R, dplyr should able to do that with inner_join() but I am not well aware with much of this package.

So, any suggestion with base R and/or dplyr will be appreciated

EDITING

I have included my original data as asked. My data is here

https://jsfiddle.net/6z6smk80/1/

DF1 is first table and DF2 is second. DF2 starts from 168th row.

All logic same , I want to join these two tables whose length is 160 rows each. I want to join by ID and take difference of column Value from both tables. The resultant dataset should have same number of rows which is 160 with extra column diff

Comment: It's unclear how you're joining the tables. If it's on a single column, you could just do `with(merge(df1, df2, by = "Sec"), abs(Value.x - Value.y)`.

Comment: His sample data set doesn't let us really see what type of join it is unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a "base R" solution using the `merge()` function on the `Term` column shared by your original `df1` and `df2` data frames:

```
df_merged <- merge(df1, df2, by="Sec")
df_merged$Value <- abs(df_merged$Value.x - df_merged$Value.y)
df_merged <- df_merged[, c("Sec", "Term.x", "Value")]
names(df_merged)[2] <- "Term"

> df_merged
  Sec Term Value
1  s1   T1    30
2  s2   T2    20
3  s3   T3    10
```

Comment: @user3050590 Please review the answers given, thanks.

Comment: What if Sec is categorical variable?

Comment: @user3050590 In the code I gave above, the `Sec` column is a factor.  I also changed the `Sec` column to a `character` and it also worked.

Comment: when  I am running it with my actual dataset, then after the merge, it is creating 6400 entries in the merged table. Originally in my both table there are 160 entries for each. Due to which, I am not getting the expected result :(

Comment: There is something going on with your data set.  Could you update your OP with a larger sample?  I think any of the 3 answers given here should work fine.  Do the other responses also give you 6400 entries?

Comment: I have updated the question and included the fiddle with the original data. I have tried dplyr inner_join and it is also giving me the same number of rows.

Comment: It looks like either `Term` or `Sec` can be duplicate?   How do you want to handle this case?

Comment: as you can see that i have not included term and sec in my original data now. but still, I am getting the same result

Answer (score 5):

Using `data.table`s binary join you can modify columns while joining. `nomatch = 0L` makes sure that you are doing an inner join

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df2), Sec)
setkey(setDT(df1), Sec)[df2, .(Term, Sec, Value = abs(Value - i.Value)), nomatch = 0L]
#    Term Sec Value
# 1:   T1  s1    30
# 2:   T2  s2    20
# 3:   T3  s3    10
```

Comment: You are seeing something which I'm not.  Please elaborate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ops desired output on second row is: `T2 s2 20`. Yours is `T2    s2    10`. You don't see it? Same thing regarding third row.

Comment: So I was right to initially join on the `Sec` column then.

Comment: You should join by `Sec` only, yes.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a dplyr question, here is a dplyr solution :

First use `inner_join` and then `transmute` to keep variables and compute and append a new one.

```
inner_join(df1, df2, by = "Sec") %>% 
  transmute(Term = Term.x, Sec, Value = abs(Value.x - Value.y))
```

Comment: What if Sec is categorical variable?