# Aggregate stock data by date from another data set

Tags: r, aggregate

I have two data sets (`data2`, `table1`); `data2` is the price data pulled from Yahoo Finance. It looks something like this:

```
          Date   Open   High    Low  Close   Volume Adj.Close
1   2016-01-29 161.61 164.43 161.33 164.37  6182800  162.7158
2   2016-01-28 160.68 160.90 158.47 160.51  8613400  158.8947
3   2016-01-27 160.57 162.23 158.61 159.30 10121900  157.6969
4   2016-01-26 159.50 161.72 159.49 161.54  5945200  159.9143
5   2016-01-25 160.41 160.72 158.67 158.70  5782500  157.1029
6   2016-01-22 160.91 161.24 159.62 160.79  7390600  159.1719
7   2016-01-21 157.81 160.29 156.88 158.60 16782400  157.0039
8   2016-01-20 157.25 158.88 154.38 157.61 16436000  156.0239
9   2016-01-19 161.45 161.62 158.81 160.02 10233800  158.4096
```

`table1` is data from an experiment that looks something like this:

```
         time2 raw_sentiment Price
1   2016-01-29      31.58333     0
2   2013-01-02    -814.75000     0
3   2013-01-03    -423.41667     0
4   2013-01-04    -408.16667     0
5   2013-01-05     596.75000     0
6   2013-01-06      55.62500     0
7   2013-01-07      15.75000     0
8   2013-01-08    -621.37500     0
9   2013-01-09     925.54167     0
```

As you can see there are gaps in days in `table1`. I want take out the `Adj.Close` numbers in `data2` that has the same Date as `time2` in `table1`. I have been using many versions of the aggregate function and it keeps giving me something like:

```
 "variable lengths differ" or "invalid type (list).
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner Join with conditions in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179805/inner-join-with-conditions-in-r)

Comment: Looks like you got your answer, but for future reference if you `dput` your data that makes it easier for us to try a solution and show you the output

Comment: Sorry I didnt know abt dput. i just though one of you guys would be helpful to do it for me :). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it,

```
data2$Adj.Close[data2$Date %in% table1$time2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data2)


data2[ Date %in% table1$tim2, .(Adj.Close) ]
```