# Data frame subset according to matching values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a `data.frame` with information on racing performance on horses. I have a variable `Competition.year` that has a "Total" row and then a row for each year the horse competed. I also have a variable `Competition.age` that describes the age the horses were in each specific year they competed.

I am trying to create a subsetted `df` based on their best racing times and the age they were when they achieved it. In the "Total" row, the racing time included is their best one. So, I need to figure out how to tell R that, when the race time in Total row is equal to whenever it is they actually achieved that time, include the age they were then in the new data frame. I am super new to R so I have no idea where to even begin doing this, I've tried some stuff I've seen on other questions but I can't get it right. Any help would be much appreciated!

My `df` looks like this:

```
travdata <- data.frame(
"Name"=c(rep("Muuttuva",3),rep("Pelson Poika",7),rep("Muusan Muisto",4)),
"Competition.year" = c("Total",2005,2004,"Total",2003,2004,2006,2005,2002,2001,2008,2010,"Total",2009), 
"Time.record.auto.start"=c(93.5,NA,93.5,96.5,NA,NA,104.2,96.5,NA,96.6,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
"Time.record.volt.start"=c(92.5,98.4,92.5,94.3,NA,105.3,98.3,94.3,102.1,99.1,107.5,NA,107.5,NA),
"Competition.age"=c(NA,6,7,NA,4,5,6,7,8,9,NA,5,6,7))
```

The desired `df` should have 223 rows (since that is the total amount of horses I have) with columns `Name`, `Competition.year=="Total"`, `Time.record.auto.start`, `Time.record.volt.start` and `Competition.age`

Comment: please make a minimal example to visualize your problem. With example and desired outcome.

Comment: Your example data frame is problematic. There sims to be 15 observations in the `Competition.age` column, while all the other columns have 14 observations. Please fix that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner Join with conditions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179805/inner-join-with-conditions-in-r)

Comment: I corrected everything now based on the answer @meenaparam gave me, sorry for the trouble! I've only started writing code and working with statistics so I'm very green :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I had to change your sample data to make sure all 5 variables only had 14 observations each. I did this by removing the final `NA` in the `Competition.age` variable. I also had to swap around the `94.3` and `98.3` values in the `Time.record.volt.start` variable so that the values lined up with what was expected in the `Total` column for the horse with `Name` equal to `Pelson Poika`.

Here is the corrected data:

```
travdata <- data.frame(
"Name"=c(rep("Muuttuva",3),rep("Pelson Poika",7),rep("Muusan Muisto",4)),
"Competition.year" = c("Total",2005,2004,"Total",2003,2004,2006,2005,2002,2001,2008,2010,"Total",2009),
"Time.record.auto.start"=c(93.5,NA,93.5,96.5,NA,NA,104.2,96.5,NA,96.6,NA,NA,NA,NA),
"Time.record.volt.start"=c(92.5,98.4,92.5,94.3,NA,105.3,98.3,94.3,102.1,99.1,107.5,NA,107.5,NA),
"Competition.age"=c(NA,6,7,NA,4,5,6,7,8,9,NA,5,6,7))
```

And here is a simple `dplyr` solution, which I think does what you want.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <-
    travdata %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(Competition.year == "Total") %>% select(Name, Time.record.auto.start, Time.record.volt.start)
df2 <- travdata %>% filter(Competition.year != "Total")
df3 <-
    inner_join(
        df1,
        df2,
        by = c(
            "Name" = "Name",
            "Time.record.auto.start" = "Time.record.auto.start",
            "Time.record.volt.start" = "Time.record.volt.start"
        )
    )
```

The dataframe `df3` should return what you were after.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for the answer and sorry about the faulty writing of the `df`, I'm a super noob in this world of statistics and code writing. If I correctly understood what you did, now in  `df3`, `Competition.year` tells me the year they achieved their best time and matches it with the age they were, right? :)

Comment: @LauraBas No problem, and yes, the `Competition.year` column in `df3` shows the year that was in that horse's `Total` row. Note that the third horse didn't have any age data for the year that they did their best race in. If this happens frequently in your data, we might be able to figure out a way to manually calculate the age of best race by using another year that does have the age in it.

Comment: Hey! The only reason that ocurred I think is because of how I wrote the `data.frame` example; when I applied it to my complete data it worked perfectly. I've calculated a bunch of different age variables using the `eeptols` package based on different conditions and they all work fine. I just needed to have an idea of at which age they usually achieve their best times and I got that now. Thanks again!!